# error publishing application could not access deployment

Tags: google-app-maker

OMG
Just as i go to deploy an app, i start getting this message :

`Error publishing application: could not access deployment (File may have been deleted in drive or you may no longer have permission to access it).`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGg11.png)

So i am the admin of my gsuite account and the owner of the file. tried turning off and on the appmaker in the admin page of gsuite.

Just before i got this message i deleted a bunch of defunct scripts from my drive. could this be related? could it be related to the projects in the cloud platform?

i have 'deployed' the app using the [PUBLISH] button which works fine!

thanks for anyone who can help

Answer (score 0):

i didnt find out the cause of the issue but this problem can be worked around by exporting the app to zip, creating a new app and importing the zip file...

just answering this here incase someone gets stuck with the above message.